# What is the variance of self-information (or surprisal)?

Tags: statistics, intuition, information-theory, entropy

The self-information of an outcome $x_i$, or surprisal, is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-information) as:
$$
I(x_i)=-\log P(x_i),
$$

where $P$ means probability. This way, the Shannon entropy can be seen as the "average" or "expected" surprisal:
$$
H=-\sum_i P(x_i)\,\log P(x_i).
$$

This is quite intuitive, and it helps understanding what Shannon entropy really measures.

But what is instead the *variance* of the surprisal?
Does this quantity:
$$
 \sum_i P(x_i)\,\big(\log P(x_i) \big)^2-H^2
$$
have any statistical meaning? Is it equivalent to anything known, or at least can it be written in a clearer way?

Thanks.

Comment: For the variance, it should be $\sum_iP(x_i)\left(\log P(x_i) \right)^2-H^2$. (Technical point -- I have no insight about its meaning, however.)

Comment: As a very smple (and not very useful) observation, this variance is the same in very different contexts: the uniform distribution on $n$ elements, and the distribution on $n$ elements which is only uniform on a subset of size $m < n$ (even $m=1$) both have this variance equal to 0.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the formula, following ClementC's comment.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, thanks for the corrections.

Comment: See also this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626522/higher-moments-of-entropy-does-the-variance-of-log-x-have-any-operational-m